# configure parametrized constructor for InjectionConstructor in UnityContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

LogUtil constructor looks as follows:

```
    public LogUtil(object classType) 
    {

        ....
    }
```

My following code works correctly..

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ILogUtility, LogUtil>(new InjectionConstructor(this.GetType()));
Logger logger = container.Resolve<Logger>();
```

I am having problem configuring the constructor settings in the configuration file. 
I configured the container registration as follows:

```
  <container>
    <register type="ILogUtility, Framework"
              mapTo="LogUtil, Log4Net">

        <constructor>
          <param name="classType" type="object">
          </param>
        </constructor>

    </register>
  </container>
```

There seems to be problem in constructor setting in the above configuration. I am unable to pass in the "type" information correctly. Its getting passed as "System.Object" as opposed to the actual class type. How do I fix the above constructor configuration?

Comment: It's just a guess, I would assume, you need to pass the type's name instead of the object. So this line `<param name="classType" type="object">` needs to be changed to something like `<param name="classType" type="MyFooTypeLogger, Framework">.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't use constructor injection.  I would do something more like this:

```
public static class Log
{
    private static readonly object SyncLock = new object();
    private static ILogFactory _loggerFactory;

    private static void EnsureFactory()
    {
        if (_loggerFactory == null)
        {
            lock (SyncLock)
            {
                if (_loggerFactory == null)
                {
                    _loggerFactory = ServiceLocator.Get<ILogFactory>();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static ILogHandler For(object itemThatRequiresLogging)
    {
        if (itemThatRequiresLoggingServices == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("itemThatRequiresLogging");

        return For(itemThatRequiresLoggingServices.GetType());
    }

    public static ILogHandler For(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        EnsureFactory();

        return _loggerFactory.CreateFor(type);
    }

    public static ILogHandler For<T>()
    {
        return For(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

It would be used like:

```
Log.For(this).Debug("Some Stuff to log.")); //Debug is defined in ILogHandler.
```

The type is passed in through the method calls and not the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that you can do this via configuration. This is more of a static setting, and you require runtime reflection. Your objects in your `LogUtil` should be castable back to their parent type, though. One thing you could try is to create an `ILoggableObject` interface and you could set the parameter as that. That is if you are looking for a method/property that is available on all controls